# Logon Automatico no SAP BExAnalyzer pelo VBAProject

Tags: vba, excel-vba

(ATUALIZADO)

No excel tenho um suplemento que dá acesso ao sistema BI, para acessar / estratificar dados em uma query ja especificada / estruturada.
No meu VBAProject estou referenciando o Add-in para chamar algumas funções específicas desse Add-in em um Auto_Open, ou seja, inicializar já ao abrir a planilha.

Nas pesquisas que fiz, o mais proximo que cheguei foi no script a seguir:

```
Sub LogonToBEx2()
Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow

logonToBW3
End Sub
Function logonToBW3() As Boolean

logonToBW3 = False

On Error Resume Next

Dim myConnection As Object
Set myConnection = Run("BExAnalyzer.XLA!SAPBEXgetConnection")

With myConnection
 .client = "800"
 .user = "usuario"
 .Password = "senha"
 .Language = PT
 .systemnumber = 1
 .system = "B1P"
 .systemid = ""
 .ApplicationServer = "B1PGroup"
 .SAProuter = ""
 .LogOn 0, True
 If .IsConnected <> 1 Then
 .LogOn 0, False
 If .IsConnected <> 1 Then
 MsgBox "something went wrong with LogOn"
 Exit Function
 End If
 End If
End With
End Function
```

A janela de logon solicita ao usuário:

> Mandate: Usuário: Senha: Idioma:

A janela já vem com os dados que chamei no script, mas o logon nao roda automatico, e mesmo dando OK, o erro a seguir é apresentado:

> SAP_CMINIT# : rc=20 > Connect to SAP gatway failed

Além do erro acima citado, chamar a função do LogOn não é suficiente. Preciso, de alguma forma, estruturar o script para que alimente a informação das variantes e siga com o OK.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde.
Pelo que eu entendi da chamada da função você pode passar somente os parâmetros referentes ao que você precisa para o login.
Ex.:

```
dim myUser as String

myUser = "Usuário"

Call LogOn(iUser:= myUser)
```

Faz sentido pra você?

Comment: faz sentido Edu, não testei ainda mas darei um retorno em breve.

Comment: Me aprofundei na pesquisa Edu, e o mais proximo que cheguei foi na atualização do post que fiz agora. mas de qqr forma, teste o call logon, mas ele apenas nao possui nessa função LogOn o argumento para iPassword.